# Link to Page if active in store view in Magento

Tags: magento

I try to add a link to a cms page if the page active in store view but don't work. If the page is only active for the store A, keeps appears in store B. Magento 1.9.1.1

```
<?php $active = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->setStoreId($storeId)->load('guia', $storeId)->getIsActive(); ?><?php if ($active == '1') : ?><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('guia');?>"><?php $aCmsPage = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->load('guia', 'identifier'); $theTitle = $aCmsPage->getTitle(); echo $theTitle; ?></a><?php endif; ?>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$cmsCollections = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->getCollection();
$attribute = "identifier"; //name of column like Identifier, Title etc.
$value = "home-page-static"; // Value of attribute
$cmsCollections->addFieldToFilter($attribute, $value);
$item = $cmsCollections->getFirstItem();
$id = $item->getData('is_active');
if($id == 1){
    echo "CMS PAGE or Static Block Exists and Enable";
}else{
    echo "CMS PAGE or Static Block is in-active";
}
?>
```